# Array to string showing as --> Array, Array, Array, Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that shows properly with print_r but when I convert it to a string it only shows `array,array,array,array` instead of the actual array values.

```
    if (!$result) {
       printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
       exit;
     }     


    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $recipients[]=$row;

     }

     print_r($recipients);

     $ids = implode(',', $recipients);
     echo $ids;
```

The output is:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 100 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 118 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 142 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 276 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 308 ) ) Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array

Comment: If you want to see a short video about some fun with arrays, I highly recommend https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding an array to the recipient array not just the id value

Use this instead

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $recipients[]=$row[0]; //gets the id assuming that is the first element in the row
}
```

Comment: thanks! accepting in 3 mins can u also open a chat with me by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

[`mysqli_result::fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) -- mysqli_fetch_row — Get a result row as an **enumerated** array. You need to access indexes of the array to get data.

To access indexes of an array in PHP, you would form a operation.

`$array[X]`

In this instance `X` can be an integer, or a string, but in this case, `mixed mysqli_result::fetch_row` returns an array in order, so you would access it in like any other array (e.g. array[0], ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = array( 0 => array( 0 => 1 ), 1 => array( 0 => 3 ), 2 => array( 0 => 100 ), 3 => array( 0 => 118 ), 4 => array( 0 => 142 ), 5 => array( 0 => 276 ), 6 => array( 0 => 308 ) );
```

To apply `implode()` function on a multi dimensional array, You could make use of `array_map()`

```
    echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
      return $entry[0];
    }, $input));
```

From php v5.5.0, [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-column.php):

```
    echo implode(', ', array_column($input, 0));
```